# SSO using Active Directory Federation Services on my .NET (C#) Application

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs

I have an application built in .NET (C# and ASP.NET). We offer our own register/login login, but a client that just signed up with us requested support for ADFS since that's the authentication service they use across their company. This is brand new to me.

1. How can I add support for ADFS on my application? I'm guessing my client will provide the new users a link to click that I'll have to process for the SSO?
2. What would my client need to do on their end? (i.e. add groups and assign our future users to those groups?)
3. What .NET (or 3rd party) libraries can I use?

Thank you!

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx. Should get you started.

Comment: @tfrege the link doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with OpenID Connect OWIN but ADFS 3.0 doesn't support this. So you need WS-Fed (WIF).

The easiest way to do this is with VS.

Create a new ASP.NET project and for "Change Authetication" select the on-premises option.

[Use the On-Premises Organizational Authentication Option (ADFS) With ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2013](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/).

Obviously ADFS needs to be configured. You need to find out what attributes the application requires in the form of claims.

Code sample which is similar for Azure AD - [Integrating a web app with Azure AD using WS-Federation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation/).